# Desplegar Proyecto con Bitnami Django Stack

Tags: django

Estoy tratando de desplegar mi proyecto hecho en Django en un servidor apache, pero me da ciertos problemas con el modulo wsgi, pues uso python 2.7 para 64 bits y no encuentro un modulo wsgi para esta arquitectura, solo para 32 y no puedo reinstalar python porque me da problemas el proyecto con las librerias, encontre bitnami django stack e instalo el proyecto de prueba, uso la documentacion pero no logro hacer el despliegue de mi proyecto en este servidor, alguien lo ha hecho, o conocen otra manera de hacer el despliegue para windows?

Comment: Con django en apache debes usar mod_wsgi, [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) django explica como.

Comment: me da ciertos problemas con el modulo wsgi, pues uso python 2.7 para 64 bits y no encuentro un modulo wsgi para esta arquitectura, solo para 32

Comment: [aquí](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi) está